# How to split String with cmd bat using delimiter as entire word

Tags: batch-file, split

How to split string with the delim=string
E.g:

split string

```
"sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz"
```

by

```
delim="MYSTR"
```

and result should be:

```
sssssMssss
___M___
zzzzzzMzzzz
```

Such code

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=MYSTR" %%A in ("sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz") do (
         set fn1=%%A
     )
```

doesn't work/ It splits only using first letter by 'M'

How to split by word?

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to replace the delimiter string by a single character that cannot occur in the string (e. g., `|`: `set "STRING=sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz"` and `set "STRING=%STRING:MYSTR=|%"`) and then to use `for /F` to split at the said character (e. g., `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=|") %%A in ("%STRING%") do echo/%%A&echo/%%B&echo/%%C`; but the disadvantage besides the forbidden character is the fixed number of tokens to be defined by `for /F`...

Comment: Precisely, but AAMOI - your original code does not split using only the *first* letter, but tokenises using **any sequence** of **any of** the characters specified, `M`,`Y`,`S`,`T` or `R`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz"

rem Do the split:
set i=1
set "fn!i!=%string:MYSTR=" & set /A i+=1 & set "fn!i!=%"

set fn
```

Output:

```
fn1=sssssMssss
fn2=___M___
fn3=zzzzzzMzzzz
```

You may review [this topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429) for a detailed explanation on the method used...

Comment: Super. But in my humble opinion, outputting the result in this code way:" for /l %%n in (1,1,!i!) do (echo !fn%%n!) " would be better.

Answer (score 1):

try with [split.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/stringutils/split.bat) (you can use both as a function or a separate bat file (does not handle well `!`,`%` and `"`)) :

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :split "sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz" MYSTR 1 spl1
echo %spl1%
call :split "sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz" MYSTR 2 spl2
echo %spl2%
call :split "sssssMssssMYSTR___M___MYSTRzzzzzzMzzzz" MYSTR 3
rem echo %spl2%

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%


:split [%1 - string to be splitted;%2 - split by;%3 - possition to get; %4 - if defined will store the result in variable with same name]
::http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1687

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=%~2%~1"
set "splitter=%~2"
set /a position=%~3

set LF=^


rem ** Two empty lines are required
echo off
for %%L in ("!LF!") DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%R in ("!splitter!") do ( 
        set "var=!string:%%~R%%~R=%%~L!"
        set "var=!var:%%~R=%%~L!"
        if "!var!" EQU "!string!" (
            echo "%~1" does not contain "!splitter!" >&2
            exit /B 1
        )
    )
)

if "!var!" equ "" (
    endlocal & if "%~4" NEQ "" ( set "%~4=")
)
if !position! LEQ 0 ( set "_skip=" ) else (set  "_skip=skip=%position%")

for /f  "eol= %_skip% delims=" %%P in ("!var!") DO (
    if "%%~P" neq "" ( 
        set "part=%%~P" 
        goto :end_for 
    )
)
set "part="
:end_for
if not defined part (
 endlocal
 echo Index Out Of Bound >&2 
 exit /B 2
)
endlocal & if "%~4" NEQ "" (set %~4=%part%) else echo %part%
exit /b 0
```

Comment: the newline insert can be done simpler : ``` setLocal enableDelayedExpansion<<br>>set br=^<<br>><<br>><<br>>rem ;<<br>><<br>>set "string=%string:!splitter!=!br!%" ```